# Select exact match in pandas row or with combined search terms

Tags: python, pandas

first question here so apologies if there are any mistakes or unclear points!

I am trying to develop a sort of search engine to look through some tabular data in a pandas dataframe, but am getting partial matches included in the search.

For example, I have a table with the following values:

```
                                     style
release_id                                
7306                                House, Deep House
37759                               House, Tech House
38319                               House, Techno
39202                               House
```

And I want to highlight the columns where the style **only** matches my input eg: 'House' with the code:

```
df_search_2 = df_search[(df_search['style'].str.match('House'))]
```

however this also returns all the other rows where the style contains the word House:

```
                                     style
release_id                                
7306                                House, Deep House
37759                               House, Tech House
39202                               House
```

Furthermore, when I try to run a search with multiple tags eg: 'House, Deep House', I end up with an empty dataframe, even if the string is in fact contained in a row.

any help on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
 df_search_2 = df_search[df_search['style'] == 'House']]
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to help, i get the error

AttributeError: eq

Comment: this gives the same outcome as my code unfortunately.

Comment: It can't be. It will return only where the row is House exactly

Comment: My bad, I realised that the data is organised slighly differently than i thought, hence the issues i keep having, i will have a go at resolving this myself. thanks again!